# npm install -g serverless return an permission error on Mac "errno -13"

Tags: macos, npm, serverless

when try run `npm install -g serverless` on Mac, get this Error:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless'

> [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless'] {
> errno: -13,
> code: 'EACCES',
> syscall: 'mkdir',
> path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless'
> }

How can install serverless package globally on macos?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As simple user try run `sudo npm install -g serverless`, then enter user password.